# Script - Compare filename date with current date

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, date, timestamps

I'm trying to compare a file with date in its name to the current datetime of the system:

Filenames are with the following format:

**FileName.yyyymmdd.hhmm.file** (e.g. File156tr.20220914.0958.txt)

I have came up with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FROM_FILE=$(ls -1 /some/directory/File156tr.*.*.txt | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{8}')
NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
DIFFERENCE=$((NOW - FROM_FILE))

if [ $DIFFERENCE -ge 1 ]; then
    echo "There are files that are older than today's date"
fi
```

The problem is that the script works perfectly when there's only 1 file of a type there.
But for example, if we have the **same file, but with different date in it's name** **(e.g. File156tr.20220913.1053.txt AND File156tr.20220914.0958.txt in the same directory)** the script won't work as the ls command will print both dates that are in the filenames.

In case there are multiple files with the same name, but with different datetime in their names (like mentioned above), how can I print out **only the newest one of them (the one that's closer to the current date)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The script I'm looking for has to print only the newest of all older
> than today files.

I would suggest that you simply build a list of the filenames that exist, remove names matching the current date, and sort the list.  The last entry in the list is the most recent.  Or if you prefer, sort the list in reverse order, and the first entry in the list is the most recent.

Assuming you don't have any `YYYYMMDD` date strings in the `/some/directory/` path portion, something as simple as this may work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mr="$(
  for f in /some/directory/File156tr.*.*.txt
  do
    [[ -f "$f" ]] && printf '%s\n' "$f"
  done |
  sort -r |
  egrep -v "$(date "+%Y%m%d")" |
  head -1
)"

if [[ -z "$mr" ]]
then
  printf 'There are no files prior to today.\n'
else
  printf 'The most recent file prior to today is "%s"\n' "$mr"
fi
```

This code iterates across all files matching the wildcard, concatenating all the filenames and passing them to `sort`.  `sort` sorts them into descending order, and removes any filenames that contain a `YYYYMMDD` string matching today's date.  The output of `sort` is piped to `head -1` to return only the single highest-sorting filename, or possibly the empty string if there are no files older than today.

Comment: Thanks man, works perfectly, I'll add some additional things according to my needs, but that's perfect and all I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

That is what loops are for:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in /some/directory/File156tr.*.*.txt
do 
  FROM_FILE=$(echo $FILE | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{8}')
  NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
  DIFFERENCE=$(($NOW - $FROM_FILE))

  if [ $DIFFERENCE -ge 1 ]; then
      echo "There are files that are older than today's date"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Please note that your approach would print the message `There are files that are older ...` for every file to which this condition applies instead of only once. Perhaps you can expand the functionality of the script to accomodate that.

Comment: Indeed, it's better than what I did, but it prints all the files that are older than the current date. The script I'm looking for has to print only the newest of all older than today files.

Comment: @joniop, then you need to define "newest" criteria. It can be something like `$DIFFERENCE -ge 1 -a $DIFFERENCE -le 7`, or you can do a play with with the `date` to find the beginning/end of month/week, and calculate two "differences". If you want to sort files, you can do `for file in $(ls -1 patern | sort)`. But that is not part of this topic. Open another one, if you want help with sorting of files.